# React Native "init" generated project contains angled braced class syntax

Tags: react-native

The following code is generated by the **react-native init ProjectName** command in the App.js file.

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
....
....
  }
}
```

Looks like instead of calling the super class constructor this syntax uses angled braces. Is this syntax an extension to the react-native or defined in es6 spec ?

EDIT2:
Answer: its an extension for the static type checker https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/

Answer (score 1):

These are type annotations for [Flowtype](https://flow.org/), a static type checker for JavaScript.

Flow is automatically enabled for React Native projects as long as the file is decorated with a `// @flow` pragma.